# How can I do performance testing of 10000+ users on Jmeter or any other opensource

Tags: automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have to perform load testing for a particular application, I know that Jmeter can't test desktop app so I can convert it as a web link for the purpose of testing.

My client has provided that there are 15000 users for this particular application?

How can I test this huge number on J meter, Do I actually need to add 15000 Vusers.?

I searched for the solution and found that we need to create different servers, is this the only option as for this  have to create 15 different servers (not feasible)

Please advise if there is any other open source so that I can do that.

Thanks !!!
p.s. I am quite new in Performance Testing

Comment: why 15 different servers is not feasible? if you run all Vuser from single machine, it will not be realistic.

Comment: ok, could you please advise , how many Vusers do I need for testing 15000 actual users.

It's just a single click on link nothing else

Comment: i agree with Dmitri T

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need 15000 virtual users to simulate this amount of real users. Real users don't hammer the server non-stop, they need some time to "think" between operations.

For instance, given the following situation:

- User does something each 15 seconds
- Page load time is 5 seconds

It means that each user sends 3 requests per minute. 15000 users will send 45000 requests per minute which stands for 750 requests per second which can be simulated by a single modern mid-end computer.

If you will proceed with JMeter I strongly encourage you getting familiarized with [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](https://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) guide - it'll allow to use your machine in the most efficient way. If you still won't be able to simulate 750 (or so) request per second - you can consider [distributed testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

In regards to other open source tools, [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/) is known for being capable of simulating huge loads on not so powerful hardware, but it runs only on Linux/Unix systems and don't have any GUI so if you need to conduct your load test fast - I would recommend going for JMeter.

Comment: just to make things more clear: there is just single link which is to be clicked that's it.

Comment: OK,
Just to make things more clear: there is just single link which is to be clicked that's it.

For doing peak Load testing, as per your comment I can interpret that should take

Number of Threads(users) -- 750  ;
Ramp up Period (sec) -- 1  ;
Loop Count  -- 20  ;

would that work,  If not then please advise.

I am very much new to Jmeter. 



My system properties are:
Inter Core i7-4610M @ 3.00 GHZ
Ram: 16 GB , 64 bit OS

I believe this is enough for the testing that I would like to perform

Comment: I would rather go for something like: Number of Threads - ~3000, Ramp-up - 150, Loop count - Forever, Duration: specify how long you would like the test to run, it should be >= ramp-up time. [Constant Throughput Timer](How to use JMeter's Throughput Constant Timer) - target throughput - 45000, put your HTTP Request sampler as a child of the timer.

Comment: In @DmitriT comments, I get where is Threads, rampup, loop coount, but where is "how long you want to run it?" I mean where we can specify how long test would run, I think it would stop after rampup time.

Comment: It will stop when either all loops are done or when what you set in "duration" input is exceeded. Click "Scheduler" box under Thread Group to be able to see/set duration

Comment: Got it!!... one more thing 3000 users/requests with rampup time of 150sec, does appear to be 750requests per minute. So how you come out with figure of 3k users and rampup time 150s?